# how to convert data frame to json format that hightcharts understands

Tags: r

I like to chart data from R to highcharts. My data frame looks like this:

```
dput(head(df,10))
structure(list(DATE = structure(c(1362027751, 1362027781, 1362027811, 
1362027841, 1362027871, 1362027901, 1362027931, 1362027961, 1362027991, 
1362028021), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), CPU = c(66L, 72L, 
69L, 72L, 69L, 68L, 71L, 73L, 63L, 57L)), .Names = c("DATE", 
"CPU"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am converting this df to json format as follows:

```
ll <- as.list(setNames(df$CPU,df$DATE))
library(RJSONIO)
data<-toJSON(ll)
cat(data, file="data.json")
```

when I look at teh data.json file, it looks something like this:

```
{
 "2013-02-28 00:02:31": 66,
"2013-02-28 00:03:01": 72,
"2013-02-28 00:03:31": 69,
"2013-02-28 00:04:01": 72,
"2013-02-28 00:04:31": 69,
"2013-02-28 00:05:01": 68,
"2013-02-28 00:05:31": 71,
"2013-02-28 00:06:01": 73,
}
```

I need my data.json file to looks like this:
[[date, value],[date,value],[date,value]]

```
   [

    ["2013-02-28 00:02:31": 66],
    ["2013-02-28 00:03:01": 72],
    ["2013-02-28 00:03:31": 69],
    ["2013-02-28 00:04:01": 72]
   ]
```

how would I do this in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want exactly that output. I think you want to have the dates and values in separate/but coordinate columns:

```
> ll <- list(as.character(df$DATE), df$CPU)
> data2<-toJSON(ll)
> cat(data2)  # You will want to add a 'file=' argument
[
 [ "2013-02-27 21:02:31", "2013-02-27 21:03:01", "2013-02-27 21:03:31", "2013-02-27 21:04:01", "2013-02-27 21:04:31", "2013-02-27 21:05:01", "2013-02-27 21:05:31", "2013-02-27 21:06:01", "2013-02-27 21:06:31", "2013-02-27 21:07:01" ],
[ 66, 72, 69, 72, 69, 68, 71, 73, 63, 57 ] 
]
```

Take a look at this SO Q&A for advice about the HighCharts side of the problem:

[Highcharts JSON load issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11958067/highcharts-json-load-issue)

(The date-times needed to be converted to character since the underlying representation of R-POSIXct objects is as "double".)

If you wanted to have the values separated by `" : "`, I suppose you could try this, but I think it will not prove to be satisfying:

```
> ll <- as.list( paste(df$DATE, df$CPU, sep=" : ") )
> data2<-toJSON(ll)
> cat(data2)
[
 "2013-02-27 21:02:31 : 66",
"2013-02-27 21:03:01 : 72",
"2013-02-27 21:03:31 : 69",
"2013-02-27 21:04:01 : 72",
"2013-02-27 21:04:31 : 69",
"2013-02-27 21:05:01 : 68",
"2013-02-27 21:05:31 : 71",
"2013-02-27 21:06:01 : 73",
"2013-02-27 21:06:31 : 63",
"2013-02-27 21:07:01 : 57" 
]
```

Comment: I've been playing around with highcharts and I think the json format needs to be like this. I was able to get it to work with this format: [
[1369540800000,12],
[1379540800000,5],
[1389540800000,18],
[1389540800000,13]
]

Comment: if you are familiar with highcharts, how would you split this json data to show date in yaxis, cpu on xaxis and possible more data like memory etc? I am little puzzled.

Comment: I'm not familiar with HighCharts. There is an SO highcharts tag.

Comment: rathher than doing it your way, is it possible to in R to convert the df in json format in [date, cpu],[date, cpu] etc